# How can I disable horizontal scrollbars in Flex components?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a few GridItem components that gets filled with dynamic data. Sometimes this data longer than the GridItem's fixed width, causing the GridItem to get a horizontal scrollbar. How can I disable this (I'm assuming you can...)

Is there a general style that handles this for other Flex components as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some Flex components, including the GridItem, have a Common property called `horizontalScrollPolicy`. Setting this to `off` will prevent a horizontal scroll bar from appearing. (There is a similar property for vertical scroll bars, `verticalScrollPolicy`.)

The other options are `on` for always on and the default value, `auto`, for showing it when needed.

The complete description of this property for GridItem and other Containers in Flex 3 can be found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Container.html#horizontalScrollPolicy).